# Decrement a progress bar on button click?

Tags: android

I'm trying to include a horizontal progress bar in my application. The idea is that when a user clicks a button the bar decrements by 1/10th of its length. Then when its 'empty' clicking a second button would set it back to 10/10.

Any ideas on how to do this? I've performed a search but most tutorials appear to deal with loading files etc and not adjusting the bar by a button click.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set up an [`onClick(...)` method](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html) and decrease the progress of the bar each time it's clicked. Use [`getMax()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html#getMax%28%29) to determine the maximum value, then divide it by 10 to get the step downward. Just make sure it doesn't go below 0.

```
int newProgress = yourProgressBar.getProgress() - (yourProgressBar.getMax() / 10);
if (newProgress < 0) {
    newProgress = 0;
}
yourProgressBar.setProgress(newProgress);
```

Then, in your second button, to reset to maximum:

```
yourProgressBar.setProgress(yourProgressBar.getMax());
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Your code worked perfectly. Im thrilled :)

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `setOnClickListener` on the button. Use `getMax()` of the ProgressBar to get the size and getProgress() for the actual progress.  `getProgress()`-(`getMax()`\10) for the next step down. If you reach 0 set 0. Same will work for the "up" button.